# How to use script to login to a website with no post request

Tags: javascript, python, unix, curl

I try to login a web site using script. (my router http://192.168.0.1)

the site looks like:

```
<input class="text" id="userName" type="text" >
<input class="text" id="pcPassword" type="password">
<label id="loginBtn" class="loginBtn" onClick="PCSubWin()"/></label>
<script>
function PCSubWin(){ 
var username = $("userName").value;
var password = $("pcPassword").value;
check username and password here.....
}</script>
```

I do some research to use curl. It seems like curl must use post request but I didn't find any. After I click login it makes a get request http://192.168.0.1/userRpm/LoginRpm.htm?Save=Save with authorized cookies. then load the main page.

What I want to do is login with this page(http://192.168.0.1) and click some button using script.

How can I do this? Any idea from python, javascript, or even unix shell command?

New Update:::

I find I should use a browser engine to do so 
selenium

I can succussfully login now. But the page is all dynamic and it shows
Please upgrade to a version 4 or higher browser so that you can use this setup tool

I will update when i'm success.

Comment: Look in the body of the GET request. While it's not standard to include a request body with GET requests, it can be done with some software. Are you monitoring the requests that are being made in the *Network* tab in your browser?

Comment: Thank you Ivan, the get request has a query parameter Save=Save. Other than that seems nothing special. I don't find userName and Password in the request.